# Do I need to Refer to the Mit license on my website?

Tags: language-agnostic

If my site uses jquery and jquery plugins, am I supposed to refer to the MIT license and give credit to the creators? Ordoes this only apply to software redistribution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [MIT license](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt) linked to by the [jQuery Web site](http://jquery.org/license):

> Copyright (c) 2010 John Resig,
>   http://jquery.com/
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of
>   charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated
>   documentation files (the "Software"),
>   to deal in the Software without
>   restriction, including without
>   limitation the rights to use, copy,
>   modify, merge, publish, distribute,
>   sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
>   Software, and to permit persons to
>   whom the Software is furnished to do
>   so, subject to the following
>   conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
>   permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of
>   the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS",
>   WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
>   OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
>   NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE
>   FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
>   CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
>   FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
>   IN THE SOFTWARE.

I'd say this is pretty self-explanatory.  If you distribute substantial portions of the software, the copyright notice must be included.

**EDIT**:

Upon reading your question again, maybe you're wondering if you have to display the notice on your Web pages somewhere.  In that case I would say no, the notice in the scripts themselves is enough.  Just don't delete them.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the others script, then you will have to state this somewhere explicitly otherwise each of those scripts have the implicit liscnce info for everyone to see.